# How can I use image data on SQL without Sorted Excemption

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got an error when trying to add the column with the images

I've tried to use case when edtrlgs.dtsnapshot IS NULL then '' else  edtrlgs.dtsnapshot end but nothing happens

I also added a IS NULL under the Where statement but nothing happens

how can I resolved the issue?

Error Code:

```
 Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 26
 The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.
```

Database Structure: employee_companyinfo

```
 empuser VarChar(50) Primary
```

Database Structure: employee_schedules

```
 empuser VarChar(50) Primary
```

Database Structure: employee_info

```
 empuser VarChar(50) Primary
```

Database Structure: employee_dtrlogs

```
 empuser    VarChar(50) Primary
 dtSnapshot Image
 dtStatus   Int
 dtLocation Char(25)
 dtDateTime DateTime
```

I did Not include thus column, thy dtsnapshot is the only problem in the Query.

Code :

```
               select
               [USER]=ei.empuser 
               ,[WORK-DATE]=convert(date, edtrlgs.dtdatetime) 
               ,[TIME-IN]=max(case when edtrlgs.dtStatus  = 1 then CONVERT(time, edtrlgs.dtDateTime) end) 
               ,[TIME-OUT]=max(case when edtrlgs.dtStatus = 2 then CONVERT(time, edtrlgs.dtDateTime) end) 
               ,[STATUS]= 
                          case 
                           when min(edtrlgs.dtStatus) <> max(edtrlgs.dtStatus) then '' 
                           when max(edtrlgs.dtStatus) = 1 then 'NO OUT' 
                           when min(edtrlgs.dtStatus) = 2 then 'NO IN' 
                          end 
               ,[LOCATION]=rtrim(edtrlgs.dtLocation) 
               ,[DAY]=datename(weekday,convert(date,edtrlgs.dtdatetime)) 
               ,[SNAPSHOT]= edtrlgs.dtSnapshot  

               from employee_info as ei 
               left join employee_schedules as esched on ei.empuser=esched.empuser  
               left join employee_dtrlogs as edtrlgs on ei.empuser=edtrlgs.empuser  
               left join employee_companyinfo as eci on ei.empuser=eci.empuser 
               group by  
               ei.empuser  
               ,convert(Date,edtrlgs.dtDateTime) 
               ,edtrlgs.dtLocation
               ,edtrlgs.dtSnapshot   
               order by ei.empuser
```

Comment: where is your table structure ?

Comment: edtrlgs.dtSnapshot Image thy causing sort error. so I did not include thus other column

Answer (score 0):

Database Structure: employee_dtrlogs

```
  empuser    VarChar(50) Primary
  dtSnapshot Image
  dtStatus   Int
  dtLocation Char(25)
  dtDateTime DateTime
```

ALTER THE COLUMN

```
 ALTER TABLE employee_dtrlogs ALTER COLUMN dtSnapshot VarBinary(MAX)
```

Code Edit: To Resolved the Slow Query

```
 [SNAPSHOT]=case when edtrlgs.dtsnapshot != '' then edtrlgs.dtsnapshot end
```

Then The Issue Was Resolved